# How to align <button> inline with text?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how one would make it so that they could have text followed by a button then more text, all on one line? This is what it might look like:

```html
<h3>Some</h3>
<button>Text</button>
<h3>!</h3>
```

Comment: add `display:inline` to block elements or use just inline elements. Or wrap them in `span`s

Comment: Make elements as display:block; ?

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks I didn't understand his question... He want elements in line or one under another like in code? If inline he can use inline, inline-block, float

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All heading tags such as `<h3>` are block-level, and a block-level element occupies the entire space of its parent element (container). You can reset it to `display: inline`, `display: inline-block` (recommend), `display: inline-table`, or even using flexbox, float etc., there are many ways.

If you can modify the markup, I suggest not to use `<h3>` for semantic reason, just use `<span>` tags or plain text would be a better choice.

```css
h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h3>Some</h3>
<button>Text</button>
<h3>!</h3>

<hr>

<span>Some</span>
<button>Text</button>
<span>!</span>

<hr>

Some
<button>Text</button>
!
```

Answer (score 2):

Give them a `float: left`

```
h3, button{
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n79gwgqk/

Answer (score 2):

As I know H3 element can contains other markup elements. Simply inline button in H3 text

```html
<h3>Hello&nbsp;<button>Say Hello</button>&nbsp;World</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `a` tag formatted as a button. Like if you used Bootstrap, `Some <a class="btn btn-primary">Text</a>!`. That should work, as long as you don't need to use some styles specific to `button` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.ele_inline {
      display: inline
}
```

```html
<h3 class="ele_inline">Some</h3>
<button class="ele_inline">Text</button>
<h3 class="ele_inline">!</h3>
```